# HashSet performance Issues in fractal renderer

Tags: java, performance

**Use Case:**

I'm trying to improve my application to render the Mandelbrot Set. I'm using HashSets to detect periodicity in the orbit of a point in the set.

For instance, the orbit of -1 is 0, -1, 0, -1... If I put each number I reach into a HashSet, I can detect infinite loops by just comparing the size of the HashSet to the iteration count. Doing this makes the render orders of magnitude faster.

**Current Implementation:**

As my program stands, the method that performs iterations receives a HashSet (of type Integer) constructed with the default constructor. This is what Java Mission Control shows me (typical output, regardless of the complexity or depth of the render): [image: Screenshot showing that hashmap.put() and resize() take up 80% of processor time]
The runtime of  the iteration method is small, almost always less than .1 ms. (At high zooms, sometimes 10ms). As a result, a LOT of these hashsets are created, filled with ~10-100k entries, and then immediately dumped. This creates a lot of overhead, since the HashSet has to be resized quite frequently.

**Things I've tried that don't work:**

- Making one HashSet and clearing it: The O(n) iteration through the backing map absolutely kills performance.
- Making the HashSet large enough to contain the iterations, using the initalCapacity argument: I tried every power of 2 from 1024 to 524288, all make the program slower. My *conjecture* as to why is the following: Since we have so many HashSets, java more quickly runs out of large blocks for the new sets, so we trigger very frequent GC, or some similar issue.

Ideally, I would want the best of both worlds: Make one object that's large enough, and then clear it. However, I can't seem to locate such a data structure. What's the best approach to storing this data?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it appears your problem is spending a bit of time resizing the underlying hashmap in the hashset. It seems you have some idea of how large the hashsets will grow to ("~10-100k entries"), perhaps you could get a small win by specifying the initialCapacity in the HashSet constructor.

Comment: That's what I meant by "making the hashset large enough". I've tried a range of values for the initial size; all of them make the runtime appreciably longer. I'll edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: Can you clarify what the type of the object is that you are putting in the hashset? Doubles?

Comment: Integers! I've updated the post as well.

Comment: Why do you put integers into your orbit cache? The intermediate values should be complex numbers.

Comment: @Searles I'm hashing my complex numbers (potentially with up to 8 double primitives into Integers)

Comment: I see. In general, from my experience, you maybe should rather use an array and do a sequential search backwards because periods are usually very short. You can do some experiments, for instance if you only do a comparison with the element that you had 60 iterations ago you already capture periodic sequences of length 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 15 and 30. Calculating one element of the mandelbrot orbit is usually much faster than finding an element in a hashset.

Comment: @Searles If you could make this an answer, I could mark it as accepted and resolve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im my experience, periodic sequences are rather short, so you should rather use an array and do a sequential search backwards. You can do some experiments, for instance if you only do a comparison with the element that you had 60 iterations ago you already capture periodic sequences of length 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 15 and 30. Calculating one element of the mandelbrot orbit is usually much faster than finding (and also inserting) an element in a hashset.

In this case it is also easier to tune this method further, eg ignore the first n elements or use some epsilon to avoid rounding errors. Using your method you would check double values for strict equality in my understanding.

Good luck!